# Can I make gcc emit the type of a object during compilation?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have C++ code like this

```
auto x = foo(bar);

x.something();
```

The type of `x` is hard to determine due to templates and overloaded arguments, and compilation fails at `x.something()` with an error which I'm struggling to interpret because I don't know what type `x` ended up having. (I know what it ought to be, if the preceding code is correct, but that might not be the case.)

Can I make gcc tell me what type `x` actually is?

Comment: The whole purpose, and the reason for the `auto` keyword is so that you don't know, and don't care what the type is. This [is an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve. No, not the one about determining the final type of an `auto` object, but the problem where you think the answer is to determine the type of an `auto` object.

Comment: Ehhm [`decltype(x)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)?

Comment: Didn't the error message tell you what is `x`? Like `class Mysterious has no member named something...`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - AFAICS, the OP has explained that with "compilation fails at x.something() with an error which I'm struggling to interpret because I don't know what type x ended up having".  He/she cannot reason about the error because he/she cannot reason about the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abuse the compiler by trying to access a non-existent type:

```
struct Foo{};

Foo foo(){ return Foo();}

int main()
{
    auto x = foo();
    using X = decltype(x)::ERROR;
}
```

then inspect the compiler error:

`main.cpp:8:28: error: no type named 'ERROR' in 'Foo'`

this tells you the type `Foo`

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb53ad2bf0dc5e2b)</kbd>